# Color changing too slow after function changes value of div

Tags: jquery, css, colors

It's hard to explain what I am experiencing. The code detects the value of a div tag. If the value is below 0, 0 or above zero; It changes to a different color. What it is doing though is it is lagging (-1 will still be gray, 0 will be either green or red but not gray, 1 will be gray)

```
function vote(vote_id, votetype) {

    $.post('vote.php', {
        id: vote_id,
        type: votetype
    },

    function (output) {
        $('#vote' + vote_id).html(output).show();


    });
    colorChange(vote_id);
}

function colorChange(vote_id) {
    var voteTotal = $('#vote' + vote_id);

    if (voteTotal.text() < 0) {
        voteTotal.css('color', '#800000');
    } else if (voteTotal.text() == 0) {
        voteTotal.css('color', '#333333');
    } else if (voteTotal.text() > 0) {
        voteTotal.css('color', '#32cd32');
    } else {
        voteTotal.css('color', '#333333');
    }

}
```

vote.php updates the database based on the vote type, then returns the new value in the database back to the function.

It seems that the function will not complete and update the value until after the function is completely closed off. I tried separating the function in the onClick that I am using `onClick="vote(x,y);colorChange(id)"`, but no success.

What am I overlooking here? I have a feeling it's simple and I am just braindead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want that after `vote` your div color should changed then you shoul call the function `colorChange` like

```
function vote(vote_id, votetype) {

   $.post('vote.php', {id: vote_id, type: votetype },
     function(output) {
        $('#vote' + vote_id).html(output).show();
        colorChange(vote_id);    
     });    
}
```

And the code for `colorChange` can be changed to

```
function colorChange(vote_id) {
    var voteTotal = $('#vote' + vote_id);
    if (voteTotal.text() < 0) {
        voteTotal.css('color', '#800000');
    }
    else if (voteTotal.text() > 0) {
        voteTotal.css('color', '#32cd32');
    }
    else {
        voteTotal.css('color', '#333333');
    }
}
```

Comment: I had those spaces in the function because I tried that. I must have missed a semicolon or something. You have the magic touch. Thanks a ton, Rohan.